# Find all values programmatically from autocomplete dropdown jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a requirement to get (Retrieve) all values from the autocomplete dropdown programmatically using Javascript or Java or JQuery;

For eg: http://view.jqueryui.com/master/demos/autocomplete/combobox.html

When I enter "A", I get all values that contains "A", likewise I want to get all the values and store it an array for automation using Webdriver. Is it possible?

My real time application is huge, it needs atleast two chars to be entered to populcate the values.

Comment: Let us know what have you tried so far.

Comment: I have been trying to read values from excel file. Programming and retrieving this way around is entirely new to me.